# jQuery ie8 attr poor performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

"I have some html similar to below contained within a loop where the parent id is dynamically generated,

```
<t:loop>
    <div id="demoid-10132165498794631" class="lineItem-container">
        <div>
            <select/>
        </div>
    </div>
</t:loop>
```

I'm trying to get the id of the parent element containing class lineItem-container.

I'm using the following script to get the id,

```
var id = $("select").parents(".lineItem-container").attr("id").substring(6);
```

The html can potentially be looped up to 1000 times which causes very poor performance in ie8. My assumption is the performance issue is caused by the attr selector.

JS Log from IE8

```
Function    Count   Inclusive Time (ms) Inclusive Time %    Exclusive Time (ms) Exclusive Time %    Avg Time (ms)   Max Time (ms)   Min Time (ms)

attr    431,334 21,609.38   12.65   14,406.25   8.43    0.05    2,234.38    0
attr    431,382 20,265.63   11.86   12,203.13   7.14    0.05    31.25   0
ATTR    239,906 20,531.25   12.02   9,125.00    5.34    0.09    8,156.25    0
attr    241,475 11,531.25   6.75    7,312.50    4.28    0.05    31.25   0
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to potentially speed this process up?

Comment: just an FYI you are missing the closing `"` after `select`. It should be `$("select")`

Comment: Hi guys, this is just a simple code snippet written to simplify the question. I do not query the dom, but rather a json object. My apology for the typo as this wasn't a copy and paste.

Comment: @George Can you post your real code?

Comment: No, it would be way to complex and hard to explain. This worked perfectly to describe my issue as Keven B and Snuffleupagus answered my answer very accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the attr selector for something as simple as an id.

replace `.attr("id")` with `[0].id`

Comment: Indeed, I just set up a [test case](http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-raw-id) to show, beat me to it.

Comment: `.prop` is a little better, but it still cant compete with native. http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-raw-id/2

Comment: I love you guys. Thanks a ton for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

It will get the **closest ancestor** and not `all the parents for the element` which might remove the extra overhead.

```
var id = $("select").closest(".lineItem-container").attr("id").substring(6);
```

Comment: do you think this will work better in conjunction with Kevin B answer?

Comment: It might if the select is deeply nested

Comment: I would definitely go with .closest over .parents simply because it results in code that is easier to read. I don't know which would be faster though.